# Table width overshoots container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with:

```
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 58px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 439px;
width: 880px;
z-index: 1;
visibility: visible;
display: block;
```

It contains a div and a table. The table tag had `width=100%`, `cellspacing=0` and `cellpadding=0`.

When I see this in Firefox with Firebug I can see that the table goes beyond the div boundaries. How do I make the table width exactly 100% of the div. In another question asked on this site i saw that the `border-collapse:collapse;` in the CSS could cause this behaviour. Hence I have removed that with no effect!

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle below I modified width to 500px to see the whole div and Chrome/FF debugger shows no problem at all.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzqH5/2/

Comment: Please add some data which exceeds the limit. I modified the div style to make it 50 px and added some mock data and some more td's and it shows the table boundary beyond the dive boundary.

Comment: using firebug i can see the border of the table exceding the div.  Can I avoid that

Comment: This [screenshot](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/7332/unledacc.png) is from Firebug, where top blue area is a div and area below is a table selected in firebug. Their width is identical.

Comment: You have got a text, that cannot be wrapped. If you want your table width to be equal to the div width, set `overflow: hidden` property of div style (but in this case you won't see the whole text) or `overflow-x: scroll` to have ability to scroll the table content.